# HTML DOM getElementById()-Node JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that adds value to different parts of my html page based on the ID of that element,
the code works perfectly no issue but what I'm looking for is a better and efficient solution to replace all the `getelementbyid` feature, if there is one of course

which mean if there is another methode to reduce the size of the code below and change it with another one

my code is below :

```
$('#public-event').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/envoi/update/' + id,
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                var html = ""
                console.log(data);

                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (id === data[i].events._id) {
                        console.log(data[i].events.title)
                        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data[i].events.title;
                        document.getElementById("eventDateTime").innerHTML = `${data[i].events.eventDate} at ${data[i].events.targetReminder} | ${data[i].events.targetAmPM}`;
                        document.getElementById("createBy").innerHTML = data[i].events.author;
                        document.getElementById("dateCreation").innerHTML = data[i].events.author;
                        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = data[i].events.caption;
                        document.getElementById("pubpriv").innerHTML = data[i].events.category;
                        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = data[i].events.location;
                        $('#monImage').attr('src', 'img/sam.jpg');
                        $('#eventImage').attr('src', 'uploads/' + data[i].events.img);
                        document.getElementById("deleteButtn").setAttribute('data-id', data[i].events._id);
                        document.getElementById("completeButtn").setAttribute('data-id', data[i].events._id);
                        document.getElementById("CommentButtn").setAttribute('data-id', data[i].events._id);
                        document.getElementById("CommentButtn").setAttribute('data-content', data[i].events.author);
                        document.getElementById("likeButton").setAttribute('data-id', data[i].events._id);
                        document.getElementById("likeButton").setAttribute('data-content', data[i].events.author);
                        document.getElementById("showComment").setAttribute('data-id', data[i].events._id);
                        document.getElementById("comment-number").innerHTML = data[i].events.comments.length +' Comments';
                        //to modify imges with dynamic
                    }
```

Thank you for any suggestion,

Best Regards,

Comment: you could use a frontend library like react or vue and populate the data inside the root element.

Comment: If security is a concern in your context, I'd suggest using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.  Otherwise someone could inject scripts.  Also you probably don't want angle brackets in the data to be interpreted (eg. if the title was "A < B").

Comment: @anees, do you mean like keep the actual html page and use react to populate data?  Is it OK work with both jquery and react?

Comment: @user2740650, thank you for the advice, is there any other advice about security  for injection script that I can benefit from it?

Comment: @Nodegeek, security is a complex subject, but a good rule of thumb is "never trust external data".  Don't assume anything about what's in the external data.  When you use  `innerHTML`, it's interpreted just as if you had written the HTML yourself, so you have to be very careful with it.  Only use it when you know for sure you constructed the HTML without any external data mixed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code comprises of both native JS and jQuery, native being the more verbose. jQuery's own slogan is: "write less, do more" – so that's one note to take away from. But also, some elements require a particular type of formatting, so this shouts for explicit statements. You could also combine the repetitive values into one statement.

```js
$('#title').text(data[i].events.title)
$('#eventDateTime').text(`${data[i].events.eventDate} at ${data[i].events.targetReminder} | ${data[i].events.targetAmPM}`)
$('#createBy, #dateCreation').text(data[i].events.author)
$('#description').text(data[i].events.caption)
$('#pubpriv').text(data[i].events.category)
$('#location').text(data[i].events.location)
$('#monImage').attr('src', 'img/sam.jpg')
$('#eventImage').attr('src', 'uploads/' + data[i].events.img)
$('#deleteButtn, #completeButtn, #CommentButtn, #likeButton, #showComment').attr('data-id', data[i].events._id)
$('#CommentButtn, #likeButton').attr('data-content', data[i].events.author)
$('#comment-number').text(`${data[i].events.comments.length} Comments`)
```

It's also noteworthy to make use of `.text` over `.html` if your values are genuinely just text and do not contain HTML. Otherwise, no harm in replacing with `.html`.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this part didn't work `$('#deleteButtn, #completeButtn, #CommentButtn, #likeButton, #showComment').data('id', data[i].events._id)
                        $('#CommentButtn, #likeButton').data('content', data[i].events.author)`

Comment: Like there is no value passed there I get there empty

Comment: I don’t follow. Are you expecting to see the data attributes in the DOM?

Comment: yes this is what I get when inpecting the html button https://ibb.co/wdCQVyY

Comment: this `data[i].events.author` should pass value to the `data-content` and same  for data-id

Comment: Ah. So you’re not familiar with data attributes and how they work with jQuery. In that case, we’ll have to use `attr` instead of `data`! See updated code.

Comment: thank you i wil but can u  light me please more I want to be familiar with data attributes and how they work with jquery

Comment: Data attributes are physical in nature when you want initial data to be read from them I.e. they appear as html attributes. jQuery will turn these into virtual data objects. Subsequently any data key-value pairs are virtual and don’t pollute the DOM because they are generally used to store arbitrary data for application logic. You can read more about it here https://api.jquery.com/data/